# twilio not receiving messages from websites

Tags: twilio, sms, messaging

The sending and recieving via my (real phone) is working fine.

But, I am not able to recieve verification codes from websites like **Yahoo**.

While **Yahoo** had sent the verification code successfully.
**Twilio** is not receiving it

I've used [THIS TUTORIAL](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134127-Receive-SMS-and-MMS-Messages-without-Responding)

Comment: Are those sites using a short ode?

Comment: @Alan its a verification message for Yahoo email sign up, so I guess its a short code or whatever I don't know what u call this stuff

Comment: Yea, if it is a shortcode, that would explain the issue. A shortcode is 5-6 digits in length. You will see that when you tested with your mobile phone. Can Twilio numbers receive SMS from a short code?
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181668-Can-Twilio-numbers-receive-SMS-from-a-short-code-

Comment: The document, Can Twilio numbers receive SMS from a short code?, was just updated, you may want to take a look - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181668-Can-Twilio-numbers-receive-SMS-from-a-short-code-.